# Show loading indicator before loading a view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mbprogresshud

I have a view, this view takes some time in loading, so after I click in a *"Show me the view"* button, it takes like 2 seconds to load.

I have no problem with this time, but I would like to add a *"Loading"* message from the moment the button is pressed until the new view is shown.

I'm using `MBProgressHUD`, but I'm using a different thread to load the view, so this is not a good idea.

---

### Code I have so far

```
[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [self presentModalViewController:testViewController animated:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

I just want to show the *"loading"* until the next view actually loads. 
Using this approach I have tons of problems in the next view for not executing `viewDidLoad` method in the main thread.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will want to do is load the other view on the main thread and once the view is loaded show the `MBProgressHUD`. Then perform the operations that are taking a while in the background using the `dispatch_async` approach.

Comment: yes, but I really need to show the MBProgressHUD before loading the view, I don't have access to that view, so I just can show the loading before load the view, not after :(    thanks